# Trying to add a regular float value to a type with float<measure>. f#

Tags: types, casting, f#

I am attempting to make a regular type with float converted into a different type with float [] and I am not sure how to proceed.

Type I wish to convert into:

```
[<Measure>] type radian
[<Measure>] type degree
[<Measure>] type km
[<Measure>] type mi
type LatLong = { Lat : float<degree>; Long : float<degree> }
```

Type I wish to convert from:

```
type Msg = {
    Mmsi: int;
    Time: string;
    Latitude: float;
    Longitude: float;
}
```

I figured a conversion such as:

```
let dist = {Lat = msg.Latitude<degree>; Long = msg.Longitude<degree>}
```

would work but it seems to not for some reason so anyone have any insight into this? Would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If there's no other formula involved, you convert a numeric type into a numeric type with a unit of measure by multiplying with the "unit" unit of measure, i.e. by one.

```
let msg = { Mmsi = 42; Time = string System.DateTime.Now; Latitude = 0.; Longitude = 0. }
let dist = {Lat = msg.Latitude * 1.<degree>; Long = msg.Longitude * 1.<degree>}
// val dist : LatLong = {Lat = 0.0;
//                       Long = 0.0;}
```

This is documented on the [Microsoft page on units of measure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure), under *Conversions*.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this can be reversed with a direct case, which will "strip" the unit-of-measure.

Comment: @202_accepted You are right. This is properly called Overloaded Conversion Function, see the [spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec), 18.2.10. In the spec you will also find a lot on units of measure.